# Can I debug PHPUnit tests in IntelliJ/PhpStorm from devspace or kubectl?

Tags: laravel, intellij-idea, phpunit, phpstorm, devspace

I have many microservices running locally in a kubernetes/devspace environment.

Based on [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-43032/Feature-request-Kubernetes-remote-interpreter) and [this](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360006660440-PHP-debugging-with-Kubernetes-on-WSL), IntelliJ and PhpStorm don't support running PHPUnit tests from within devspace or kubectl.

So in the meantime, I am just running a bash script manually as a script via `Run | Edit Configurations...`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

devspace enter -c foo php artisan config:clear;

kubectl exec -it deploy/foo -- \
  vendor/bin/phpunit \
  tests/MyExamples/ExampleTest.php -v \
  --log-junit reports/unitreport0.xml \
  -d memory_limit=-1
```

Is there a better way to do this using devspace?  I'd like to be able to at least integrate it with the test runner instead of running a script.

If not, is there any way to extract the current test name or class in IntelliJ/PhpStorm so that I can pass it into the script as a parameter?

Also, is there any way to make the lines clickable in IntelliJ/PhpStorm?

`/bar/foo/tests/MyExamples/ExampleTest.php:123`

Comment: Wow, this is a weirdest use of kubernetes I've ever seen. Why not local docker-compose?

Comment: I would say, 100% go docker, why are you running it this way?

Comment: Turns out the correct way to do this is relatively straightforward.  Devspace supports setting up an sshd server (https://www.devspace.sh/docs/configuration/dev/connections/ssh), and then you can run the remote shell in intellij: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/remote-development-starting-page.html#start_from_IDE.  (It's better documented for vscode: https://www.devspace.sh/docs/ide-integration/visual-studio-code)

Comment: We're coordinating several services---not just this one---in a dev environment in k8s/devspace, so creating a parallel docker experience would be redundant.

Comment: I am very curious now, what do you have that using docker is "redundant"? The idea of it is to virtualize (simulate) your production environment so you can run your code and see that it works, what do you mean with redundant? You are paying for devspace, but docker, locally, is free. Asking out of curiosity as I have never encounter an "issue" like yours to depend on an external service to run tests

Comment: @Matiaslauriti  Creating two parallel development environments seems like a waste of time.

Comment: But I still do not get what do you mean with two parallel environments, are you paying for  devspace? It could literally be free for you (or your team), just using docker and having the needed services up and running

Comment: @matiaslauriti I appreciate the suggestion, and I fully understand that I could do the same thing in Docker Compose.  But the title does indicate very clearly that I need to do this in a devspace/kubernetes environment.  I will edit the question to make this more obvious.

Comment: Yeah yeah! As I said before, I am curious, just trying to understand your usage on why having a remote environment works better for you than a local, it should be a very big pain, as you wrote on your answer, locally would just be clicking a button on PHPStorm, just trying to understand why you prefer that than a local docker env. Thank you for sharing info!

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this in IntelliJ/PHPStorm is to use `sshd`.  This is well supported in devspace with a tiny amount of configuration.

First, add this line to the `devspace.yaml` file to set up sshd on your instance:

```
ssh: {}
```

Then you should be able to log in via ssh.  Note that you will have appended some lines to your `.ssh/config` file, so you may want to verify these settings:

```
ssh foo.bar.devspace
```

Then in IntelliJ, go to `File` → `Settings` → `Tools` → `SSH Configurations`, add a new entry:

**Host**: `foo.bar.devspace`

**Username**: `devspace`

**Port**: `10659` *(NOTE: confirm this value in your ~/.ssh/config file.  The default of 22 is probably incorrect)*

**Authentication Type**: `Key pair`

**Private key file**: `/Users/<myusername>/.devspace/ssh/id_devspace_ecdsa` *(replacing myusername with your own user name)*

ensure that **Parse config file ~/.ssh/config** is checked

Then, in `File` → `Remote Development`, click on `SSH Connection` → `New Connection`, then choose the connection we just created from the **Connection** dropdown (all the other fields should be greyed out), and click **Check Connection and Continue**.  (If this doesn’t work, your shell may be set incorrectly---make sure the `$SHELL` is not set to something like `/sbin/nologin` inside devspace).

In the "Choose IDE and Project" dialogue, choose an IDE and version and set the Project directory to some value---it doesn't look like you can set it to be empty, so maybe your home directory will work.  You may get some confirmation dialogues from docker desktop as it installs Intellj/PHPStorm on the devspace client.

Run Intellij---it will connect to your devspace environment.  You can load your project from the container. It will likely prompt you to install the PHP plugin and restart.

Now you should be able to **Run** a unit test---click on the Green arrow beside a test to make sure it works.  You should also be able to **Debug** a unit test with a breakpoint.